# How to convert an MKV to MP4 with Subtitles

Tags: conversion, mp4, matroska, subtitles

I have an MKV with subtitles.  I want to convert it to MP4, but HandBrake does support encoding subtitles from anything other than a DVD.

Is there a way to do what I want?  I'll take anything on either Mac or PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mkvextract](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html) to pull the subs and fonts out of the .mkv, then use [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) to re-encode the video, adding the sub track in the video filters.